# Accept a word then print every letter of that word on new line in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a program in Java that will accept a string/word then print every letter of that word on a new line. For example, the machine accepts `zip` then outputs:

```
Z
I
P
```

How do you do this in java? Any simple method or way of doing this would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercise_4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        a = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter your words");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(word.charAt(a));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Two people upvoted the question! really?

Comment: Do you need to worry about code points?  All of the answers seem to assume each char is a printable character... not true in most encodings.

Also noticed that your output was in uppercase while the input is lowercase.  Is that a requirement?

Comment: One of the rules here is not to post a question you haven't worked on first yourself.  This looks like a homework problem in a CS 1 class that you should be able to figure out by reading the text or attending class.

Comment: I found this helpful

Answer (score 9):

Easy:

```
for (char ch : word.toCharArray())
    System.out.println(ch);
```

Comment: I tend to use the `charAt()` approach to avoid having to copy all the characters to a new array. For this assignment it definitely will not make a difference though, and this is probably more readable.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Please explain how it works though?

Comment: @user2433900: look at [JavaDoc of the string class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). This is an enhanced for loop that prints every character of the char array created by the `toCharArray()` method of your string.

Comment: like a what all the different parts mean and do eg what is the ch and how does it make it go on a new line every time

Answer (score 5):

```
String word = scan.nextLine();

for(char c : word.toCharArray())
  System.out.println(c);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
for(char c : word.toCharArray())
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: please explain to me how thus works

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
    System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercise4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your words");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        String word = scan.nextLine();

        for(char a : word.toCharArray())
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This, too, was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Split word into characters

```
String[] parts = string.split("");
```

print characters, one per line

```
for(String char : parts){
    System.out.println( char );
}
```

Comment: -1: Such a simple task requires no regular expression and also not a `String` for each and every character. Also: `char` is not a valid variable name.